# JQuery Datatables. Is there a way to remember the state of the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Everytime my datatables table refreshes the scroll state is lost and it jumps back to the top.
is there a way to remember the scroll position?

I have `"bStateSave": true,` but it does not remember the scroll as well

My refresh function:

```
if(null!=oTable) {
            var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
            oSettings.sAjaxSource = "/jsp/getData.do?methodName=dataView&filters="+getFilterData();
            if(goToFirstPage) oTable.fnPageChange( 'first' ,false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
            startRefreshTimer(refresh.period);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve  and restore  the `scrollTop`of an element or window. Something like:

```
//set
var scrollTopSaved = [somelement].scrollTop;
//retrieve
[someelement].scrollTop = scrollTopSaved;
```

[**MDN scrollTop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.scrollTop)
[**JQuery scrollTop**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)